# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not set

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata, hadoop-streaming

Hey All can u please help me in clearing following error ? I am getting this when I am running Mapreduce job fopr inserting data into hbase tables from hdfs files. using `HFileOutputFormat.class` , earlier i ran the same using `MultiTableOutputFormat.class` it was working fine , but it was taking so much time while inserting data into hbase tables .

So can u please help me ... :) 
        ***

> job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);
>             job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);
>             job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
>             job.setOutputFormatClass(HFileOutputFormat.class);
>             job.setMapperClass(Map.class);      HTable hTable = new    HTable(conf,"ARK_3000");
>                      HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, hTable);
>
> ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
>   as:reddym (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output
>   directory not set. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidJobConfException: Output directory not
>   set.

Thanks Madhusudhana Reddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the output directory is not write protected and try again Don't use directories like the root of a drive. hope this helps
Regards

EDIT : try adding this where it asks you for the output directory

```
HFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(<YOUR_LOCATION>));
```

or `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(<YOUR_LOCATION>));`

And you need to mention the output directory so it knows where to write the data to.

Hope this helps you further with your problem, let me know if you need any more help. as i am always happy to help.

EDIT 2 : You need to mention an output directory because the tables you are writing to is stored in the memory and when you end the program all of the data in the memory is lost. 
For example if the program crashes all of the data is lost unless it is written to disk. So the data saved to the output directory is a backup in-case anything goes wrong.

I hope this answers your question clearly for you, if you need any more assistance leave another comment
Regards
Tom

Comment: Thanks for Quick response :) Am very new to hbase . so can u please explain more detail what to add in code to rid of this error. Actually i haven't added the following line to the code , if i needs to add this line what to be write in cubeOutputPath as we are writing in hbase table directly , why to need of mentionthe output directory.  HFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, cubeOutputPath);

Comment: Yes sir Just have seen in some  article of adding path  like u are saying , MR code is running now with out errors but still it hasn't finished any maps as of now . And  what my question  is Why needs to mention the output directory as we  want  to write to write data into hbase tables .???

Comment: Awesome:) got answer ... Thanx once again. :)  and I ran above code for 500 files which has 5000 rows and in each row  it has 32 columns  in each files . and each files has the 5.5 mb in size. earlier the MultiTableOutputFormat.class code was taking to finish nearly 24 hrs to finish :( :( .and it hasn't finished any Maptasks as of now how much time it should take finish total about3 gb data to insert into hbase tables ???

Comment: It is hard to say as it depends on the speed of your computer i would say between 12 and 48 hours. and also Mark this answer as correct by clicking on the tick below my votes so i know your 100% satisfied

Comment: Awesome:) got answer ... Thanx once again. :)  and I ran above code for 500 files which has 5000 rows and in each row  it has 32 columns  in each files . and each files has the 5.5 mb in size. earlier the MultiTableOutputFormat.class code was taking to finish nearly 24 hrs to finish :( :( and it hasn't finished any Maptasks as of now how much time it should take finish total about3 gb data to insert into hbase tables ???  And one more question is theer any MultiHFileOutputFormat  class to write data into multi tables ?/

Comment: I have found this [link] (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-issues/201104.mbox/%3C833563967.33101.1301945105792.JavaMail.tomcat@hel.zones.apache.org%3E) but i don't have any experience with it hope this helps anyway.